# Grouping shortcuts with different parameters in Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

I have created many different windows shortcuts for pgAdmin.exe with the target database given as a command line argument. For example:

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pgadmin3.exe" /s database1
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pgadmin3.exe" /s database2
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pgadmin3.exe" /s database3

I'd like to get all of them grouped under one icon in Windows 7 Taskbar but at the moment they show separately (one icon per shortcut). "Always group" is on in taskbar properties.

Is there a way to do it without additional software like Bins or a way to do it with some free alternative or should I perhaps create the shortcuts differently?

Comment: There are some 3rd party software that make taskbar icons with pinned executable. You can then uninstall the program and it will still work.
If it is okay with you I can post it as answer ?

Comment: These tools will make it under one icon, but when the programs are launched they will be shown as different icons. Is this what you want ?

Comment: No not really, I'm not launching the shortcuts from taskbar but from desktop (or launchy). After launch I would like to see them all under the one icon. Curiously when I launch the program with different parameters straight via command line they show up under one icon. So the problem lies in passing parameters to Windows shortcuts.

Comment: If it works when you launch it from command line, it should also work from bat files and you can create batch files for each db (batch files will work similar to Shortcuts). Have you already tried that ?

Comment: Yeah I tested it already but it seemed clumsy with the opening command prompt window. Tested it again but this time adding the start command `start "pgAdmin" "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pgadmin3.exe" /s database1` So now it seems like a tolerable solution..

Comment: add EXIT at the end of bat, it will close the command prompt window.
making it cleaner.

Comment: Well, actually adding `start` to the pgAdmin-command is sufficient to close the command prompt window right away. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to create bat-files with the command

```
start "pgAdmin" "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pgadmin3.exe" /s database1
```

This way they get grouped under one icon in Windows 7. Adding the command `start` at the beginning makes the underlying command prompt close right away.